# Как в woocommerce изменить стоимость продукта на странице оформления заказа?

Tags: php, wordpress, ajax, woocommerce

На странице checkout есть дополнительные поля, которые влияют на конечную стоимость товара.
Я бы хотел динамически изменять общую стоимость в зависимоси от заполненных полей.

Если использовать ниже приведённый хук, то работает, но не совсем так как бы хотелось.

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'set_custom_price', 50);

function set_custom_price() {
  if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
  return;
  $getcart = WC()->cart->get_cart();
  foreach ( $getcart as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
     $cart_item['data']->set_price( $price );
  }
}
```

Есть ли способ динамически менять стоимость используя AJAX?
Пробовал так:

```
    $('#my-btn').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://colis.by/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                action: 'my-action',
                sum: '120'
            }, 
            beforeSend: function( xhr ) {
                $('#my-btn').text('Загрузка, 5 сек...');    
            },
            success: function( data ) {
                $('#my-btn').text('Отправить'); 
                console.log( data );
                $(document.body).trigger("update-order-review");
            }
        });

    });


add_action( 'wp_ajax_my-action', 'test_function' ); 
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my-action', 'test_function' );  
 
function test_function(){
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
   return;
 
     $sum = $_POST['sum'];

     $getcart = WC()->cart->get_cart();
       foreach ( $getcart as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
         $cart_item['data']->set_price( $sum );
         print_r($cart_item['data']);         
       }      
    die;
}
```

В правильном ли направлении я двигаюсь? Есть ли у кого какие-нибудь идеи как мне получить ожидаемый результат?

Answer (score 0):

Решил свою проблему добавлением переменной в сессию

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my-action', 'test_function' ); 
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my-action', 'test_function' );  
 
function test_function(){
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) return;
 
     $sum = $_POST['sum'];

     WC()->session->set( 'fee_sum', $sum );
    
    die;
}

add_action('woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'set_custom_fee', 50);

function set_custom_fee( $cart ) {
  if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) return;
    
   $sum = WC()->session->get( 'fee_sum' );
     
   if ( $sum && $sum > 0) {
      $cart->add_fee( 'Дополнительная стоимость', $sum );
   }
}
```